# Is there any way to connect locally running code and Microsoft teams channel to communicate. Basically a bot?

Tags: botframework

I Have established a connection between "Microsoft bot framework" and "Microsoft teams channels". Chat/Web Bot is communicating as expected. 
Now I have an HTML page(below is the code), **This HTML page has a chatbot which needs to be connected with Microsoft teams**. For EXample: if I send "Hi" message from HTML page, this message should reach to Microsoft teams.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="chat" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" src=''></iframe>
</body>
<script>

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'BotConnector ' + 'vU-0WBkWsO4.Pun532fUbjOmaM-JV4rv0u3rQ982B5B1VR4at5sNar0');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
    console.log("e",e)
      if (xhr.readyState == 4  && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("chat").src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/CLIENT_LENOVO?t="+response
      }
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

**IMAGES FOR REFERENCE**
1) Microsoft bot framework [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omMIH.png)
2) Microsoft teams [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHHaN.png)

Comment: I'm unclear on the setup. Can you clarify on what this UI is? This is another interface that users will chat with the bot? Typically a bot is setup, and then configured so that multiple "channels" (MS Teams, Slack, Telegram) can communicate with it.

Comment: For the time being, I a doing on local UI.
On the local UI, there is iframe from where the message will be sent to Microsoft teams.
To summarize: 
1) I am able to connect "local chatbot" with "Microsoft bot framework".  
2) also able to connect "Microsoft teams" with "Microsoft bot framework". 
connect means able to echo the message.
Now, how do I connect "local chatbot" with "Microsoft teams", and send to and for messages between them?

Comment: Ok, so you want the bot to be somewhat of a middle man between the users on Teams and your custom local UI. Will the bot be conversing with the two (in this simple scenario) participants? Or is it just a way to connect the two?

Comment: So sorry for not getting your question, I'll try to explain again. I want to connect a simple HTML page with Microsoft teams or vice-versa. For example: If I send a message "Hi" from the HTML page, this message should reach to Microsoft teams.
Presently, The HTML page can echo the message(repeat the message) whatever I send. similar is working fine for teams, message is getting echoed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying. This isn't something that is typical in a bot scenario, but the awesome thing about the bot framework is that you can do it!

Please take a look at (friendly neighborhood bot expert Eric's) [Super Simple Proxy bot](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/SuperSimpleProxyBot). Essentially, in the `OnMessageActivityAsync` method, just call to the `ProxyToSharedConversation` function which does all the work. But it's [not much code](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/SuperSimpleProxyBot/blob/master/MessageProxyService.cs) at all.